# How to make text edit function by Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textedit

Same as title the following, thx~

[image]

Comment: Use an editor like tinymce, ckeditor etc

Comment: @TomHsieh It is rich text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called RTE, or Rich Text Editor. There're many RTEs, and one of them for rails is `wysiwyg-rails`, it provides the Froala WYSIWYG HTML Editor javascript and stylesheets as a Rails engine for use with the asset pipeline.

You can follow this tutorial to install it: https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-rails